# DB2 Iseries 4 Issue casting date from decimal

Tags: sql, db2

I have decimal fields (DECIMAL(8,0)) that contain dates as 5122019 for may 12th 2019 and 12122020 as December 12th 2020.

I've tried several ways to convert including `DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(decimalField),'MMDDYYYY'))`

but they return null. What's the best way to do this with a decimal 8,0 field when the single digit months don't contain a leading zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use `LPAD()` so the string has 8 characters:

```
select t.*,
       DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(LPAD(decimalField, 8, '0') , 'MMDDYYYY'))
from (SELECT 5122019 as decimalField
      FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8ae73cdf73e4c63819ce0f3daf5c2927) is a db<>fiddle.

You might want to be sure that the `DD` component is zero-padded.  Otherwise, you cannot reliably make the conversion, because 1112020 could be either November 1st or Jan 11th.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to right-pad the date decimal string with zero:

```
DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(
    RIGHT('0' || CHAR(decimalField), 8), 'MMDDYYYY'))
```

For a decimal string value such as `12122020`, which has a two digit month, the above logic would operate on that same value.  For values such as `5122019`, we would left pad with zero first to obtain `05122019` before trying to convert to a date/timestamp.

All this being said, the *best* option here would probably be to store dates as date types, and not as decimals or string representations.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Is it directed towards my answer?

Answer (score 0):

rather than concatenating strings...

A better option might be to use `DIGITS()`

```
DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(DIGITS(decimalField) , 'MMDDYYYY'))
```

It's not that the zero isn't there, it's that the **implicit** conversion via `CHAR()` loses it.